# Disable IAX module on asterisk. Only allow SIP

Tags: asterisk

I wanted to see on what ports my ubuntu machine was listening on; therefore, I ran the command `netstat -tulpn`.

When I ran that command I found out that I was listening on port `4569`.

That is being used by Asterisk. Since I do not plan to use the IAX protocol and only stick to SIP, how can I disable IAX so that my computer stops listening on that port?

Maybe I have to enter `disabled=true` at `/etc/asterisk/sip.conf` ?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the solution. The list of all the modules that asterisk loads can be found in here:

https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+modules

In my case I did not wanted to load the IAX modules since I do not use it. I added this lines:

```
noload => chan_iax.so
noload => chan_iax2.so
```

to `/etc/asterisk/modules.conf`

then restarted asterisk:

```
asterisk -rx 'core restart gracefully'
```

after asterisk reloaded I can see that port 4569 no longer shows up when running `netstat -tulpn`.